# Memory Issues with Worksheets

Tags: epplus

I am seeing what I perceive to be excessive memory use when attempting to get the names of all of the worksheets in a workbook. As soon as I try and open the worksheets inside of the package (excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets) my test uses ~ 400 MB of memory and takes around 20 seconds to finish that line of code. I am wondering if this is a normal amount of load for the tool to be using for a 30 MB .xlsx file with 3 worksheets. My larger issue is that the tool seems to be keeping around 1.2 GB of memory even after I am done with this ListWorksheets task. So a) 1.2 GB seems excessive for a 30 MB file and b) the memory should be deallocated when the tool is done with it should it not?

[Memory plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ADYx.png)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WorkBook_OpenAndCloseWorkBook_MemoryBehavesCorrectly()
    {
        var template = Path.Combine(testDocumentsRootDirectory, @"Templates\30MB_File.xlsx");
        var outputSmokeTest = Path.Combine(testDocumentsRootDirectory, @"Results\MemTest.xlsx");
        for (int x = 20; x > 0; x--)
        {

            smokeTestWorkbook = new Workbook(key);
            if (File.Exists(outputSmokeTest))
                File.Delete(outputSmokeTest);
            smokeTestWorkbook.Open(template);
            var worksheets = smokeTestWorkbook.ListWorksheets();
            smokeTestWorkbook.SaveAs(outputSmokeTest);
            smokeTestWorkbook.Close();
            //GC.Collect();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a reference to the workbook
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Open(string workbookPath)
    {            
        var loggerString = "Open";
        if (File.Exists(workbookPath))
        {
            try
            {
                logger.Track(loggerString);
                excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(workbookPath));         
            }              
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.TrackException(loggerString, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtain an array of worksheet names
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string[] ListWorksheets()
    {
        var returnValue = new List<string>();
        var loggerString = "ListWorksheets";
        try
        {
            logger.Track(loggerString);
            returnValue.AddRange(excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(excelWorksheet => excelWorksheet.Name));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.TrackException(loggerString, ex);
            throw;
        }
        return returnValue.ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SaveAs document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void SaveAs(string filename)
    {            
        var loggerString = "SaveAs";
        try
        {
            logger.Track(loggerString);                            
            excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filename));                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.TrackException(loggerString, ex);
            throw;
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Close()
    {
        var loggerString = "Close";
        try
        {
            logger.Track(loggerString);
            excelPackage.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.TrackException(loggerString, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 30 mb is large, but that should normally not be an issue. But without the code as to how you open the file there is little we can do.

Comment: Apologies, I added some of the code for reference. I have had success getting the memory to release with the dispose but I am still wondering why so much memory is necessary.